# Can I track form submissions through Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to track form submissions on the website in Google analytics.
I was considering to add the following code to the SUBMIT button,

```
<input id=”contact-submit” class=”button” type=”submit” value=”Submit” onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'requestinfo', eventAction: 'submit', eventLabel: 'undergrad'});">
```

But can I do all of this through Google tag Manager to improve efficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways so it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Below are a few options that will work on contact forms and any other type of click action.

1) You can setup a link trigger in GTM with HTML5 data parameter and class or ID

```
<input id=”contact-submit” class=”button” type=”submit” value=”Submit" data-form="Contact Us" data-whichpage="Home Page">
```

**In GTM, fire on gtm.linkClick and use element ID -> equals -> contact-submit**

2) If you have a confirmation page you can setup a dataLayer and use custom dimension to capture the information.

On your confirmation page setup a data layer using PHP or something:

```
dataLayer.push({
"Form_Name": "Home Page",
"Form_Type": "Contact Us",
"Custom_Dimention_2": "Parameter 2"
});
```

Then in GA create the custom dimentions and match them up with corresponding fields in GTM